Jupyter Notebook and Python Script return different YOLOV8 instance segmentation masks
I've been running a pretrained YOLOV8 model for instance segmentation. For testing and development I've been using an Anaconda Jupyter Notebook, which I converted into a Python script before deployment.
Here is the code for the minimum reproducible example:
from ultralytics import YOLO
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import PIL

print(torch.cuda.is_available())

model = YOLO("YOLO/yolov8x-seg.pt")

image = PIL.Image.open("YOLO/test.png")

results = model(image, verbose=False)
plt.imshow(np.logical_or.reduce(results[0].masks.data.cpu().numpy()).astype(np.uint8)*255)
plt.show()

This is the test image I have used
Here is the (correct) mask from the Jupyter Notebook:

and here is the result from the Python script:

You can see that the Python result has these weird blocks towards the edge of the bounding box.

The code is exactly the same for both versions
The Python virtual environment is directly created from the Jupyter environment export (and I double checked: identical Python version and identical versions for all libraries)
Same CUDA version (12.4)
Same hardware (both examples were executed on the same machine - GPU is RTX 3070 Ti Laptop)
Both networks use the same pretrained weights (available for download here)

My first guess was that some libraries had different versions between the Jupyter Notebook and the Python environment, but I manually checked them and they were identical.
I also tried manually setting the floating point precision for the Python Script in case this is caused by some aggregating precision error across the network weights, but this didn't work either.
I read that Anaconda uses IPython, which might cause different behaviour, but I'm unsure what to do with this information.
I also can't simply reduce the bounding box size, because the position and size of these artefacts is not predictable in a moving image. Reducing the bounding box size results in parts of the masks being cut off occasionally.
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?
